# Run GitLab pipeline job whenever another job is run

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to run a job (say, `job2`) whenever another job (say `job1`) is run without affecting any other independent job (say, `job0`). Basically, I don't want do define the rules twice (or even multiple times, as after job2 may come many more jobs). I want `job2` to be dependent on `job1`.

The keyword `dependencies` does not match my use case, as I don't (always) work with artifacts.

I tried to use `needs` like the following:

```yaml
stages:
  - first_stage
  - second_stage

job0:
  stage: first_stage
  script:
    - echo "Job that always runs"

job1:
  stage: first_stage
  script:
    - echo "Job that sometimes runs"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      when: never

job2:
  stage: second_stage
  script:
    - echo "Job that exclusively runs when job1 runs as well"
  needs:
    - job1
```

The problem here: When the rules in `job1` are *not* met, I get the following error:

```
 yaml invalid error | Unable to create pipeline
    'job2' job needs 'job1' job, but 'job1' is not in any previous stage
```

That means `job0` (an example of an independent job) can't run because the whole CI-Definition is suddenly invalid.

It seems this is not the way I should write GitLab job dependencies?

Is the `rules` keyword the only way to actually add/remove jobs from the pipeline?

Do I then have to define these rules for every job? I know I can reference them like this:

```yaml
job2:
  rules: !reference [job1, rules]
```

But this also seems needlessly verbose.

Any help, also on good practices regarding these kinds of dependencies, would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to look at the [`! reference`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#reuse-rules-in-different-jobs) keyword that might help to prevent duplicating rules.